# Xcode 4 ios database tools

Tags: database, xcode4, console

Does anyone know if XCode 4 has a debug utility similar to the Developer Tools in the Chrome browser?  In particular, I want to be able to view the database and tables my app creates in real time in the XCode 4 simulator.

Thank you.

Comment: No, not really. If you use Core Data, you could probably write you own logging-classes (it's potentially all in your memory) but this would require substantial effort, I guess.